# SED whitespace/line break match - Linux

Tags: linux, bash, sed

basically what I want to do is use SED (linux version) to make changes in a HTML file. When I execute that code, i get an "unknown command" error because sed can't tell what whitespace or line breaks are apparently.

```
sed 's|<a href="es/map-button.html">
            <div class="map-button">|<div id="confirmation" onclick="confirmation()" class="map-button">
            <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
              function confirmation() {
                var answer = confirm("Access map? (uses internet)")
                  if (answer){
                    window.location = "google.maps.com";;
                  }
                  else{
                    //alert("Returning to current content")
                  }
              }
//-->
            </script>|g' *.html
```

my delimiters are the "|" that you see here.

Comment: What is the question? What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Sorry should have specified more. Basically when I execute that code, i get an "unknown command" error because sed can't tell what whitespace or line breaks are apparently.

Comment: Strange, I get the error "unterminated 's' command", which is due to the fact that the arguments to the `s` command must not contain literal newlines.

Comment: you cannot just using sed like this. sed only read one line to pattern space at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Using the change command of sed.

```
sed '/<a href="es\/map-button\.html">/{
    N
    /<div class="map-button">/c\
<div id="confirmation" onclick="confirmation()" class="map-button">\
<script type="text/javascript">\
<!--\
function confirmation() {\
    var answer = confirm("Access map? (uses internet)")\
    if (answer){\
        window.location = "google.maps.com";;\
    }\
    else{\
        //alert("Returning to current content")\
    }\
`}\
//-->\
</script>
}' *.html
```

---

```
/address/c\
text
```

Delete the pattern space.  With 0 or 1 address or at the end of a 2-address range, text is written to the stan-dard output